# Angular: Add to each request a random number in order to disable caching for IE

Tags: django, caching, angularjs

IE is heavily [caching xhr requests](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1418). To overcome this problem users suggested to add a random number to the url. For example [here](https://github.com/npina/nestor-shop/issues/5#issuecomment-15384384)

Whereas this will work, I'm looking for a way to add a random number globally / disable IE caching globally, and caching has also be disabled for resource xhr get calls. I'm guessing that I could achieve this goal by using one of the following approaches. But I'm not sure what I exactly have to do..

a) Using `$httpProvider.defaults.transformRequest`

b) by using `request/response promise chaining` which have been added in v [1.1.4](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/4ae4681)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an old issue with IE.  Not sure how to muck with Angular's $httpProvider (or that I want to), but here is a function that adds a random value to any url, whether or not it already uses a query string:

```
function noCacheUrl(url) {
    var urlParser = document.createElement('a');
    urlParser.href = url;
    var q = "nc" + Math.random() + "=1";
    q = urlParser.search ? urlParser.search + "&" + q : "?" + q;
    return urlParser.protocol + "//" + urlParser.host + urlParser.pathname + urlParser.hash + q;
}
```

Note that the ***name*** of the added query param is random, not the value, making it less likely to collide with any existing name/value pairs.  Example: &nc0.8578296909108758=1

http://jsfiddle.net/LgjLe/

Comment: Thanks. I guess combining this function with an http request would be a valid approach. Nevertheless I solved the issue with adding no cache headers to the response at server side, see my answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the caching issue with adding no-cache headers to the response at the server, using Django and a custom middleware.

```
class NeverCacheXhrMiddleware(object):
    """
    sets no-cache headers for all xhr requests
    xhr requests must send the HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH header to 
    be identified correctly as a xhr request using .is_ajax()
    see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547/making-sure-a-web-page-is-not-cached-across-all-browsers
    """
    def process_response(self, request, response):
        if request.is_ajax():
            response['Cache-Control'] = 'no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate'
            response['Pragma'] = 'no-cache'
            response['Expires'] = '0'
        return response
```